# Getting values from Elastic-Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'll initial get dates from elastic stack. 
At first just any data set, just to proof it works.
I set up the connection and than I try to get a data set.
I show you my code and the error message below.
You got any suggestions where to look for the missing values?
Thanks, Frank

```js
            string elasticSearchConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ElasticSearchConnection");
            string elasticSearchIndex = configuration.GetValue<string>("ElasticSearchIndex");
            Uri uri = new Uri(elasticSearchConnectionString);
            ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).DefaultIndex(elasticSearchIndex);
            ElasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
            IGetResponse<_doc> result = ElasticClient.Get<_doc>(1);
```

[image: IGetResponse<_doc> result = ElasticClient.Get<_doc>(1);]

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on GET: /hybif/_doc/1
>   Audit trail of this API call:
>    - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz9q9.png) BadResponse: Node: http://10.211.226.31:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.3149405
>    OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 404 from: GET
>   /hybif/_doc/1
>
> Request:
>
> force it to be set on the response.>
>
> Response:
>
> ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
>
> 00:00:00.3149405
>    OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 404 from: GET /hybif/_doc/1
>    Request:
>   
>    Response:

Answer (score 0):

That works now...:

The search at my RecordsRepository.cs:

```
        var result = ElasticClient.Search<_doc>(document =>
            document
            .Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.DataRecordId)
                    .Query(search)
                )
            )
        );
```

and the _doc.cs:

```
public class _doc
{
    [JsonProperty("contextName")]
    public string ContextName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resourceId")]
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("componentId")]
    public string ComponentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("processStepId")]
    public string ProcessStepId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dataRecordId")]
    public long DataRecordId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public object Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```